# Absurd ClassCastException using maven-jetty-plugin

Tags: maven, servlets, jetty, classcastexception, maven-jetty-plugin

Does anyone know what might be causing the following `ClassCastException: org.eclipse.jetty.server.Request cannot be cast to org.eclipse.jetty.server.Request`

This happens inside the `doGet(HttpServletRequest req, ..)` of my `HttpServlet` when I try: `Request baseRequest = (Request) req;`

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.mortbay.jetty</groupId>
    <artifactId>jetty-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>8.1.5.v20120716</version>
    <configuration>
        <jettyXml>src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/jetty.xml</jettyXml>
        <connectors>
            <connector implementation="org.eclipse.jetty.server.nio.SelectChannelConnector">
                <port>8081</port>
            </connector>
        </connectors>
            <stopPort>18080</stopPort>
            <stopKey>STOP</stopKey>
        </configuration>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>mysql</groupId>
                <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
                <version>5.1.13</version>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
</plugin>
```

Comment: did you check to see if the runtime jar is different from that of compile time ?

Comment: everything should be the same since I'm running it locally with the jetty plugin. How could I verify this?

Answer (score 2):

You need to ensure jetty-server isn't packaged as part of your actual application; this'd normally be done by setting scope to provided:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
    <artifactId>jetty-server</artifactId>
    <version>${jetty.version}</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```